# PHP: URL format www.mysite.com/users/33

Tags: php, friendly-url

I've seen URL's like this around and I'm just wondering how it is they are used.

Until now I've been using www.mysite.com/users/?id=33

How can I use the other format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paul Peelan's answer is correct if a little verbose :-)  Put this in your .htaccess file in the root of your site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^users/(\d+)$ /users/?id=$1
```

This will match /users/33, /users/1, /users/12345 etc and redirect to /users/?id=12345.

This requires that your Apache configuration has the `mod_rewrite` engine enabled.  See [the mod_rewrite docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for further information.

Comment: Thanks richsage, just what i needed!

Comment: i think i need to enable the RewriteEngine in httpd.conf but I'm not sure where to find it. I use a Mac btw. thanks

Comment: Not sure where it is on the Mac, but something like `LoadModule rewrite_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_rewrite.so` is needed.  You might need to enable the Rewrite module specifically - if you get stuck, http://serverfault.com/ might be the better place to ask for server config probs :-)

Comment: cheers! this works for numbers but if i want to replace with text it doesn't. is this due to the \d+ in the regex?

Comment: Yes. `\d+` matches 1 or more numbers. If you want strings or anything else, you'll need to replace `\d+` with an appropriate regex :-)

Comment: cheers, used RewriteRule ^Profile/([a-z]+)$ Profile/?id=$1 but it only works on lowercase. not quite sure how to do caps as well

Comment: ^Profile/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ Profile/?id=$1

Answer (score 2):

You will have to use the "mod-rewrite" and e.g. an .htaccess file.
Apache will then send the urls according to your settings in the .htaccess file.

E.g.:

## Various rewrite rules.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  # If your site can be accessed both with and without the 'www.' prefix, you
  # can use one of the following settings to redirect users to your preferred
  # URL, either WITH or WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix. Choose ONLY one option:
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITH the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://example.com/... will be redirected to http://www.example.com/...)
  # adapt and uncomment the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
  #
  # To redirect all users to access the site WITHOUT the 'www.' prefix,
  # (http://www.example.com/... will be redirected to http://example.com/...)
  # uncomment and adapt the following:
  # RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

  # Modify the RewriteBase if you are using Drupal in a subdirectory or in a
  # VirtualDocumentRoot and the rewrite rules are not working properly.
  # For example if your site is at http://example.com/drupal uncomment and
  # modify the following line:
  # RewriteBase /drupal
  #
  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  # RewriteBase /

  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Regards,
Paul

Comment: By the way, the example above is taken from Drupal!

Comment: thanks paul, found a good article at http://www.phpriot.com/articles/search-engine-urls/2

Comment: Great! Glad I could help! 
/Paul

Answer (score 0):

I know you have already selected an answer for this question, but this is quite useful to know. The PHP framework Codeigniter allows you to use URLs like this by default. I found it a lot easier to do URL rewriting this way. Further information about this, including code samples, can be found at http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html